Working with FIT files in QGIS - how to visualise trackpoints with symbology by speed
I'm using QGIS 3.28.2-Grenoble. I exported my activities from Garmin Connect Web - FIT files.
Then, I used FIT Plugin for QGIS to load FIT files to *.sqlite database https://github.com/jkall/qgis-fit-plugin/wiki

After opening the SQLite database I see the following layers:

The only layer that visualises anything is "Tracks" (line) and "Sessions" (point). However, it's the trackpoints that contain the information about heartrate or speed, which I want to use for symbology of the line (similar to what Garmin does in their webUI).

But when I enable trackpoints layer nothing shows up. I enabled tracks as well but with trackpoints above the tracks layer and, as you can see, nothing shows up (I changed symbology to bright orange):

Not sure what I'm missing but ideally I would like to achieve a continuous line but using the attributes of trackpoints, just like in Garmin UI. Is it possible?

I think the GPX segment Importer plugin should do the trick. It has an option to calculate the speed between two points.
screenshot
